# Heatmap showing only one line of annotations

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to create a Seaborn heatmap with annotations.
The heatmap colors displays properly, but annotations are not complete.
I am getting a consistently truncated display to only the first line.
[Heatmap I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVJOk.png)

Code I am using

```
# Libraries to help with reading and manipulating data
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

# Libraries to help with data visualization
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns

# Load built in flights into dataframe and pivot
    flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
    flights = flights.pivot_table(index='month', columns='year', aggfunc=sum, values='passengers')

# Create heatmap with annotations
    ax = sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, linewidths=.2, fmt="d")
    plt.title("Heatmap Flight Data")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: remove the indentations. this will break the code.

Comment: It's a known bug.

Comment: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3478

Comment: interestingly, when i correct the indentation and run the code, i get the full image !!

Comment: @D.L you matplotlib version may be less than 3.8 try this and see `matplotlib.__version__`

Comment: yes, it is clearly a versioning thing.  Both this question and the "duplicate" question code worked well for me with seaborn version `0.13.0` which i just did a new pip install for.

Comment: Yes, that was it, I upgraded to Seaborn 0.13.0 and the numbers are coming to all lines.